# Access localhost from external source

Tags: localhost

I have activated the IIS package for windows, and, I created an index.html file into the `wwwroot` directory.

Upon visiting `localhost/index.html`, it works fine.

But what do I have to do, so that someone else may see the page?

I tried to putting `http://(my IP adress)`, but it doesn't work, it opens up the modem settings page.

(If required, this is my modem : Huawei SmartAX mt882a ADSL modem)

How do I get my page to be visible from outside?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have a public address and also you need to configure the server to allow external connections.

I don't have IIS but it needs to have a "is public" configuration setting.

Comment: Its not IIS. IIS already accepts port 80.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the router to forward the port 80 to the private ip of the development computer